# Computing the matrix representation of the second fundamental form of a cylinder

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the generalised cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the parametrisation

$g(u,v) = (f(u)cos(v),f(u)sin(v),u)$

for $u \in (a,b) \text{ and } v \in (0,\pi).$ Find the matrix representation of the  second fundamental form $II_x$ for any $x$ on the surface.

I know that the second fundamental form is given by $I(W_x X, Y)$, where $W$ means the Weingarten map. To compute this I need to get the Gauss map first, since the Weingarten map is it's derivative. To compute the Gauss map I suppose I should start like this:

$p\longmapsto \dfrac{\partial_1\times\partial_2}{||\partial_1\times\partial_2||}$,
where $\partial_1=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}$ and $\partial_2=\frac{\partial g
}{\partial v}$.

Unfortunately I do not get any further, as I do not know how to concretely go forward. Could you help me?

Comment: I think you may want $g(u,v) = (f(u)cos(v),f(u)sin(v),u)$ instead of $g(u,v) = (f(u,v)cos(v),f(u)sin(v),u)$; what do you think?  Cool question, ***+1!!!***.  Cheers!

Comment: You are right I will make an edit.

Comment: In any differential geometry text, you'll find a recipe for the second fundamental form in terms of second-order partial derivatives of $g$. You most definitely do *not* want to differentiate the Gauss map.

Comment: By the way I think you might want $\partial_1 = \partial g / \partial u$ and so forth, not $\partial_1 = \partial f / \partial u$ etc.

Comment: Again you are right I made an edit.